# Computing the Laplace transformation of a nonlinear pulse

Tags: laplace-transform

The piecewise function is

$f(t)=$

\begin{cases} 
      0 & t\leq 0 \\
     \sqrt{t} & 0 \leq t\leq 4 \\
      2 \cos(t-4) & 4\leq t <4+\pi/2\\
      0 & t >4+\pi/2\\
   \end{cases}

I have expressed it as:

$f(t)=\sqrt{t}[H(t)-H(t-4)]+2 \cos(t-4)[H(t-4)-H(t-(4+\pi/2)]$

However, this doesn't seem to simplify into something where the delay formula can be used. I know that

$L(\sqrt{t})=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{s^{3/2}}$ and $L(\cos(at-b)=\dfrac{s\cdot\cos(b)+\sin(b)}{s^2+a^2}$

but I'm not sure how to proceed with this question.

edit:

I have now written this as

$f(t)=\int _0^4 \sqrt{t} \cdot e^{-st} dt + 2\int _4^{4+\pi/2} \cos(t-4) \cdot e^{-st} dt$

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to provide such a simple and unenlightening answer, but to your last question: yes.

First note that,
$$
e^{-st}f(t) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0 \\
e^{-st}\sqrt{t} & 0 \leq t < 4 \\
2e^{-st}\cos(t-4) & 4 \leq t < 4+\frac{\pi}{2} \\
0 & t \geq 4+\frac{\pi}{2} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Then using the definition of the Laplace transform and some basic properties of the integral operator,
\begin{align*}
L(f(t)) &:= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt \\ \\
&= \int_{0}^{4}e^{-st}\sqrt{t}dt + 2\int_{4}^{4+\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-st}\cos(t-4)dt \\ \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\text{erf}(2\sqrt{s})}{2s^{3/2}} - \frac{2e^{-4s}}{s} + \frac{2(se^{-4s}+e^{-\frac{1}{2}(8+\pi)s})}{s^2+1}
\end{align*}

where the left integral (for the $\sqrt{t}$ term) is not known in closed form so we make use of the error function,
$$
\text{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^z e^{-t^2}dt
$$

but the right integral (for the $\cos$ term) can be carried out with integration by parts.

I'm curious if there is a more elegant solution to this as well, but as far as I can tell, that's as nice as it gets.

Did this problem come from a textbook? I'm curious about the context. In many applications, we are concerned with the Laplace transform of a sum of "forcing functions" that may "switch on" at various times. For example, if instead your problem had,
$$
f(t) := 
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0 \\
\sqrt{t} & 0 \leq t < 4 \\
\sqrt{t} + 2\cos(t-4) & 4 \leq t < 4+\frac{\pi}{2} \\
\sqrt{t} & t \geq 4+\frac{\pi}{2} \\
\end{cases}
$$
it would be much simpler to evaluate. In the context of linear ordinary differential equations, the above would represent a square-root input "activating" at time 0 and a quarter-period sinusoidal pulse input at time 4.

I mention this because if the piecewise function you gave was an interpretation of something else, perhaps a mistake was made in the interpretation, leading to this otherwise challenging problem.

One other thing that may make it possible is multiplying $f(t)$ by some function $g(t)$ before taking the laplace transform, where there is some known relationship between $L(f(t))$ and $L(g(t)f(t))$ that can be exploited after the fact to "undo" our application of $g(t)$. For example,
$$L(tf(t)) = -\frac{d}{ds}L(f(t))$$
Unfortunately I don't see a $g(t)$ that exactly works for you.

The last thing I can think of that may be worth exploring is the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

If any of these methods were to work and give you an answer in terms of simple functions, it would mean that Wolfram was wrong and that,
$$\int_{a}^{b}e^{-st}\sqrt{t}dt$$
does have a closed-form solution. This is why I am skeptical.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your lengthy answer! This problem came from an assignment, not a real life example or anything. I typed the problem as it was given. Is there a way to solve it when it is written in the Heaviside form using the delay formula? I was thinking you could use:

$f(t)H(t-a)=g(t-a)H(t-a)$ where $g(t) = f(t+a)$ ?

Comment: The problem with that is still in evaluating the square-root term. You would still need to know $L(g(t)) = L(\sqrt{t+a})$ which as far as I can tell is not a known [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+of+sqrt(t%2Ba)).

Comment: What is the textbook title and chapter this is from? Sorry to be so inquisitive about that haha

Comment: I threw a couple new ideas at the bottom of my answer; still no simple solution though...

Comment: Thank you for your help, enjoy the bounty! The question was simply in an assignment I received - perhaps my lecturer just made it up. Interesting answer you've provided though, thanks again!